# Powershell copy files with specific name

Tags: powershell, file-copying

I tried to copy files from one folder to another which have word HIGH at the end of name of files in their names but didn't get it. Any suggestion?

```
$dest = "C:\transform"
$source = "D:\result"
get-childitem $source - filter ".jpg" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -match "HIGH" | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $.fullname $dest}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_.DirectoryName` holds the folder name, `$_.Name` the file name :

```
$dest = "C:\transform"
$source = "D:\result"
Get-ChildItem $source -Filter ".jpg" -Recurse |
    ? { $_.BaseName -match "HIGH$" } |
    % { Copy-Item $_.FullName $dest}
```

Or, as pointed by @Walter Mitty, a simpler :

```
Copy-Item -Path $source -Filter "*HIGH.jpg" -Destination $dest –Recurse
```

(in this case `-Filter` and `-Include` seem to behave the same)

Comment: should use `HIGH$` since the OP said at the end of files. `cmatch` might also be a good idea to enforce case.... but that is overboard most likely. Also the -Filter could just be `"*HIGH.jpg"` if it really is just files. Perhaps the op needs to clarify the question....

Comment: `$_.Name -match "HIGH$"` wouldn't work because of the file extension, but `$_.BaseName -match "HIGH$"` would :-). Thanks, corrected. It fits better.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to copy files from one folder to another is the Copy-Item cmdlet.
Take a look at the -Path -Include -Destination and -Recurse parameters.

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/60a19812-67ab-4b58-a6f5-34640edafbb0(v=wps.630).aspx